# Can python's Dash be used to create a dashboard with input addresses and use geopy to output the corresponding longitude and latitude?

Tags: python, dashboard, geopy

I wish to create a dashboard where a user can input a list of addresses separated by `\n` and then the dashboard will output a list of corresponding latitude and longitude values seperated by `\n` or as a pandas dataframe with two columns or original address and then the new values.

Can this be done through Dash or is there a better tool for it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Unfortunately, this is not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow. Per the post [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for this. Unfortunately I can't show what has been done so far as I am stuck on the first step of finding a tool that can do what I want so I am not sure how to progress.